# Unity ReadPixels() is slowing game down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the following to take the content of a camera and write it to a material. This works fine with 1 camera, but when I attach it to 4 cameras and write to 4 materials it drops the FPS to 12 - 13 FPS. Is there something I can do to optimize this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RenderToTexture : MonoBehaviour {

    public Material mat;
    [HideInInspector]
    public Texture2D renderedTexture;

    void Awake () {
        renderedTexture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);

        mat.mainTexture = renderedTexture;
    }

    void OnPostRender(){
        renderedTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.width), 0, 0);

        renderedTexture.Apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: [HideInInspector], if you use private, you don't need this attribute, :)

Comment: It is accessed from other classes

Comment: then you can use public properties: public Texture2D abc {get; private set;} as well. The same, no need to use the attribute.

Comment: Are you making some kind of portal clone?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get it, I just needed to make the texture smaller. This seems to work:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RenderToTexture : MonoBehaviour {

    public Material mat;
    [HideInInspector]
    public Texture2D renderedTexture;

    void Start () {
        renderedTexture = new Texture2D(300, 300);
        mat.mainTexture = renderedTexture;
    }

    void OnPostRender(){
        renderedTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect((camera.pixelWidth - 300) / 2, (camera.pixelHeight - 300) / 2, camera.pixelWidth, camera.pixelHeight), 0, 0, false);
        renderedTexture.Apply();
    }
}
```